# How to differentiates buttons and behaviour in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items; Each item has a "Details" button beside it.

When the "Details" button it is pressed, I would like to show under the list the details of that element.

So far so good. I managed to do it. Even if it doesn't seem the best way. Now the problem is:

When I press, for the first time, a button, it shows the details of that item. But when I press again, regardless of the button, it close it. This is because I don't understand how to differentiate them. So for closing the "Details" I can just hit any button, and I don't want it.

My desired behavior would be (pseudo code):

```
if details_not_showing:
   show_details(id==button_pressed)
else:
   if details_showing == details_from_button_pressed
      close_details()
   else
      show_details(id==button_pressed)
```

Hoping this make some sense, I leave you with my terrible code under this.

Imports

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
```

Function

```
function MonthArticles() {
  const { user_id, year, month } = useParams();
  const url =
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/" + user_id + "/posts/" + year + "/" + month;
  const url_retrieve_author = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/retrieve-author";

  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("id", user_id);
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formdata,
  };

  const [article, setArticle] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setArticle(data);
      });
  }, []);

  const [author, setAuthor] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url_retrieve_author, requestOptions)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setAuthor(data);
      });
  }, []);

  const [details, setDetails] = useState(false);
  const [articleId, setArticleId] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        Articles writte in {year}, {month} - By{" "}
        {author.map((author) => (
          <div key={author.id}>{author.last_name}</div>
        ))}
      </h2>
      <h4>List of articles below:</h4>
      <ul>
        {article.map((article) => (
          <div key={article.id}>
            <li key={article.id}>
              {article.title}{" "}
              <button
                id={article.id}
                type='button'
                onClick={() => [
                  setDetails((currentDetails) => !currentDetails),
                  setArticleId(article.id),
                ]}
              >
                Details
              </button>
            </li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>

      {details ? (
        <div>
          <h3>Showing details</h3>
          {article
            .filter((a) => a.id === articleId)
            .map((filteredArticle) => (
              <div>
                <h4>Post created in: {filteredArticle.date_created}</h4>
                <p>{filteredArticle.text}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in your code is that `details` is toggled from `true` to `false` on any button click.

The solution with minimal changes would check the current `articleId` before toggling the `details` value.

> ```
> onClick={() => [
>   setDetails((currentDetails) => !currentDetails),
>   setArticleId(article.id),
> ]}
> ```

Should be changed into:

```
onClick={() => {
  // `details` is set to `true` if a new article is clicked.
  // When pressing the button of the same article multiple
  // times, the value is toggled.
  setDetails(article.id !== articleId || !details);
  setArticleId(article.id);
}}
```

---

There is also a solution that only uses a single state, but requires more code to change.

```js
// `false` if no details, otherwise an article id
const [detailsId, setDetailId] = useState(false);

// Lookup the article of which details must be shown.
// Performance can be improved by using the useMemo hook.
const details = article.find(article => article.id === detailsId);
```

This essentially uses `detailsId` as a boolean. It contains `false` if no details must be shown. But instead of `true` we use the article id, to store both the fact that details must be shown, and the id of the article that must be shown.

`details` looks up the article based on the `detailsId`. This variable (not a state) helps simplify the view later on.

Your `onClick` handler then becomes:

```
onClick={() => {
  // Set `detailId` to `false` if is the same as the current article id,
  // otherwise set the current article id.
  setDetailId(article.id !== detailId && article.id);
}}
```

Finally you need to update the view:

```
{details && (
  <div>
    <h3>Showing details</h3>
    <div>
      <h4>Post created in: {details.date_created}</h4>
      <p>{details.text}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check on click if the id doesn't change then return `null` to hide the details, if not set the new article `id` to show the details.

```js
function MonthArticles() {
  const { user_id, year, month } = useParams();
  const url =
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/" + user_id + "/posts/" + year + "/" + month;
  const url_retrieve_author = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/retrieve-author";

  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("id", user_id);
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formdata,
  };

  const [article, setArticle] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setArticle(data);
      });
  }, []);

  const [author, setAuthor] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url_retrieve_author, requestOptions)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setAuthor(data);
      });
  }, []);

  const [details, setDetails] = useState(false);
  const [articleId, setArticleId] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        Articles writte in {year}, {month} - By{" "}
        {author.map((author) => (
          <div key={author.id}>{author.last_name}</div>
        ))}
      </h2>
      <h4>List of articles below:</h4>
      <ul>
        {article.map((article) => (
          <div key={article.id}>
            <li key={article.id}>
              {article.title}{" "}
              <button
                id={article.id}
                type='button'
                onClick={() => [
                  setDetails((currentDetails) => !currentDetails),
                  setArticleId(prev => {
                    if (prev === articleId) return null
                    return article.id
                  }),
                ]}
              >
                Details
              </button>
            </li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>

      {details ? (
        <div>
          <h3>Showing details</h3>
          {article
            .filter((a) => a.id === articleId)
            .map((filteredArticle) => (
              <div>
                <h4>Post created in: {filteredArticle.date_created}</h4>
                <p>{filteredArticle.text}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in your buttons onClick functions you do this:

```
onClick={() => [
      setDetails((currentDetails) => !currentDetails),
      setArticleId(article.id),
]}
```

The first line toggles whether or not the details secions is visible. All buttons currently toggle the details visibility. What you want is to only do this when it is the button corresponding to the currently displayed details.

```
onClick={() => {
      //If no details are visible, show them
      if(!details) setDetails(true);   
      //If details are visible, and this is the corresponding button, hide them
      else if(article.id == articleId) setDetails(false); 
      setArticleId(article.id);
}}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful. I wasn't aware I could write if-statements inside React code.
This easy solution worked perfectly.